# What is the difference between INSERT and CREATE VERTEX in OrientDB?

Tags: sql, graph-databases, vertex, orientdb

I've recreated my database as a `graph` instead of a `document` database, as it represents a social network. However, I'm unsure as to what the difference is between a vertex and an ordinary record. I'm still able to use `INSERT`, which is very useful because of the `UPSERT` option, and the `CREATE VERTEX` options doesn't have that option.

Additionally, I'm wondering if I do, in fact, need to use `CREATE VERTEX`, if an `UPDATE VERTEX` will be available.

Comment: Could you create a feature request to implement **upsert** for `CREATE VERTEX`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no so much difference between CREATE VERTEX, and INSERT in the underling implementation but is strictly suggested to use CREATE VERTEX, because it can do additional check! as well as all specific sql operation like DELETE VERTEX!

for the UPSERT in the CREATE VERTEX will be really nice submit a feature request :)

Comment: What "additional check" does it perform?

Comment: The target class is V or extends it

Comment: @Lvca Is that necessary? Because then `OUser` not being a `V` is a concern.
@tglman I've submitted a feature request :)

Comment: You can always change it with: `alter class OUser superclass V`

Answer (score 0):

While using Pyorient 1.4.9 and OrientDB 2.2.17,

I found that if you have a Generic Class, you can only insert new records using `INSERT INTO MyGenericClass ...`. If you try to use `CREATE VERTEX MyGenericClass ...` the pyorient client hangs and becomes unresponsive. Despite pyorient being unresponsive, the bottom line I would said is that you cannot insert a Vertex in a class that does not inherits the `V` class.